# How to integrate date picker with datagridview?

Tags: c#, sql, gridview

In my app, I am running a query on employees to find out how much order each one has.
I want to add to that a filter of date. So I created two date time pickers and built a function for them. Where & how should I integrate between them, or can I just input that in the query some how?

Code:

```
   private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.employeesTableAdapter.Fill(this.nORTHWNDDataSet.Employees);
        using (NorthWindDataContext db = new NorthWindDataContext())
        {
                var query =
                from d in db.Employees
                select new EmployeeData
        {
            FirstName = d.FirstName,
            EmployeeID = d.EmployeeID
        };
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = query;
        }
    }

    public bool CheckDate(DateTime date)
    {
        DateTime floorDate = FromDate.Value;
        DateTime roofDate = ToDate.Value;


        if (date > floorDate && date < roofDate)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }




    private void displayOrdersToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (NorthWindDataContext db = new NorthWindDataContext())
        {
            if (db.Employees == null)
            {
            }
            EmployeeData currentEmployee = (EmployeeData)dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;

            var query =
              from o in db.Employees
              where o.EmployeeID == currentEmployee.EmployeeID 
              select new
              {
                  orderNumber = o.Orders.Count()
              };

            dataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = query;
        }
```

something like

```
 where o.EmployeeID == currentEmployee.EmployeeID && o.Orders.Where(x=>x.OrderDate.Value.Date>FromDate.Value.Date&&<ToDate.Value.Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to subclass both the `DataGridViewColumn` and `DataGridViewCell` classes to host any control of your choosing.

This article on MSDN explains the process in more detail, and even includes some sample code:
[How to: Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx)

You can also find a complete sample on Code Project: [Generic DataGridView V2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/GenericDataGridView.aspx)

Comment: something like

 where o.EmployeeID == currentEmployee.EmployeeID && o.Orders.Where(x=>x.OrderDate.Value.Date>FromDate.Value.Date&&<ToDate.Value.Date)